# Make a class serializable in PCL

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, portable-class-library

I am working on a cross platform application (using Xamarin) which has interaction with a server application. These two applications need to exchange data using the TCP protocol, and to achieve that I need to make some classes Serializable.

So what I want to do is to set these classes in a portable class library so that it can be referenced by both my cross platform application and the server.

The issue I am facing is that marking a class Serializable does not seem to be possible in a PCL. I tried downloading "Microsoft .NET Portable Library Reference Assemblies" and adding reference to the dll but it says that they are already referenced by default.

```
[Serializable] //I need to use this flag
public struct Product
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Price")]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Brand")]
    public string Brand { get; set; }
}
```

What should I do to be able to use Serializable in my PCL ?

Thank you

Comment: You could use a cross platform serializer like protbuf-net which is very fast and has also as far as I remember a version for PCL. See https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/ and https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/

Comment: You have to use `DataContract` related attributes.